# How to use rigidbody simulation for animation?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I want to be able to add rigid body physics to my gun when my animation character dies so the gun will drop smoothly, because it is hard to animate things dropping in small areas.

I am not making a game, therefor I do not need to use the game engine instead of cycles or blender render.

Comment: So all you want to know is how to add rigid body physics to an object? Or is there something else?

Comment: yes , pretty much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [Blender 2.66](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.66/Rigid_Body_Simulation), you can press *Rigid Body* in *Properties > Physics*.

To enable and disable control of the rigid body with the animation system, keyframe the *Animated* checkbox.

See the [wiki for documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aSergof/GSoC2012/Documentation).

Comment: Thank you for your help , Ill check now to see if it works :)